# Switch between AVCaptureSession and ARKit - do I need to recalibrate the AR session?

Tags: swift, arkit, avcapture

I am working on a project where I need to take high quality photos( ReplayKit quality is not enough) and combine them with positions from ARKit frame. I need to take about 10 photos with positions and each of those photos should be in the same coordinate space.

Since it's impossible to use ARKit and AVCatpureSession simultaneously, I'm thinking about getting position from ArKit, pausing AR, taking a photo via new AVCaptureSession, and playing back again the AR session.

The question though is if it's possible to resume AR session, without having too big drift to origin point of first session ?

It would be great to confirm, before implementing this experiment.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think this is generally difficult (some say you can, some say you can't).

In theory though if you have a camera on a tripod and can keep it really still then you could save the position and rotation of the camera when you stop the session, then create a new session and load these parameters to use as offset.

I.e. in the second session your position is:

```
new_position = position + old_position
```

This will obviously only work if you can really minimise any movement between sessions (like with a tripod and remote trigger).